# Using gt, gte, etc. in WHERE subquery in Squeryl ORM

Tags: scala, orm, subquery, squeryl

I've recently started evaluating [Squeryl ORM](http://squeryl.org) and it looks great but finally I came to an SQL query that seems to be problematic to "build" with Squeryl.

I'd like to get all products that have a quantity which is higher than the average quantity of all products.
In SQL, this would look like

```
SELECT * FROM product p WHERE p.quantity > (SELECT AVG(quantity) FROM product)
```

I already found out that Squeryl supports `in()`, `exists()` and `notExists()` in a `where`-clause subquery. But since Squeryl also supports the `avg` aggregation, I hoped that something like this would be possible:

```
val avgQuantity = from(products)(p => compute(avg(p.quantity)))
val oftenOccuringProducts = from(products)(p => where(p.quantity gt avgQuantity) select(p))
```

Sadly, this raises:

```
type mismatch; found : org.squeryl.Query[org.squeryl.dsl.Measures[Option[org.squeryl.PrimitiveTypeMode.FloatType]]] 
required: org.squeryl.dsl.NumericalExpression[?]
```

Of course, I'm able to do that in 2 queries (first, obtain the average quantity, then use it in a second query) but I'm wondering if it is possible to do it **with one query including a subquery**.

Is this impossible with Squeryl or am I just missing something?

I'd appreciate any help if this is possible or not, and if, how.

Thanks,

Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the same discussion the mailing list, [a fix was pushed](https://github.com/max-l/Squeryl/commit/557292558863d18033c73f716435bd371e4fc1c3) to the Squeryl master branch and will be included in the next release.

Comment: Could you please post a short snippet how the query given by sebastian_oe will look like?

Comment: Hi, I just tried out the fix from the project's master branch and it's working as expected:

`val avgQuantity: org.squeryl.Query[org.squeryl.dsl.Measures[Option[Double]]] = from(products)(p => compute(avg(p.quantity)))` which you can then use in
`val oftenOccuringProducts = from(products)(p => where(p.quantity gt avgQuantity) select(p))`.

This creates the query as 1 SQL statement, as expected.
(Note that I added the type explicitly to the 1st statement to make it clearer.)